# Display several results with one SQL query (group by?)

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I want to show several results of one query, but I need to group some of these results. I think it's better for you to see my problem :

I have this table that shows several trainings :

[image]

And when you click on a row, it'll expand and show exercises that correspond to the training's id (here's example values) :

[image]

To get all the exercises by training, I made the following query :

```
SELECT E.id_entrainement, E.intitule_entrainement, E.date_entrainement, EX.id_exercice, EX.reps, EX.poids, M.nom_exm FROM entrainements E, exercices EX, exercices_muscles M WHERE EX.id_entrainement = E.id_entrainement AND EX.membre = E.id_membre AND M.id_exm = EX.id_exercice_muscle AND id_membre='".$user_id."' GROUP BY E.id_entrainement
```

But when I put in my code the `$data['id_entrainement']` for example, it shows me only the first value got by the query as you can see here :

[image]

And when I remove the `GROUP BY` clause from my query, I have this :

[image]

I don't know if it's really helpful for you, but here's my php code :

```
echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<h1>Vos entraînements</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Référence entraînement</th>
            <th>Nom de l\'entraînement</th>
            <th>Date de réalisation</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

        $i=0;
        //$getTrainings = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM entrainements WHERE id_membre='".$user_id."'");
        $getTrainings = $bdd->query("SELECT E.id_entrainement, E.intitule_entrainement, E.date_entrainement, EX.id_exercice, EX.reps, EX.poids, M.nom_exm FROM entrainements E, exercices EX, exercices_muscles M WHERE EX.id_entrainement = E.id_entrainement AND EX.membre = E.id_membre AND M.id_exm = EX.id_exercice_muscle AND id_membre='".$user_id."' ");
        while ($data = $getTrainings->fetch()) {
            $i++;
            echo '
            <tr class="plusExpand">
                <th scope="row">' . $i . '</th>
                <td>' . $data['id_entrainement'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $data['intitule_entrainement'] . '</td>
                <td>' . date("j/n/Y", strtotime($data['date_entrainement'])) . " " . date("G:i", strtotime($data['date_entrainement'])) . '</td>
                <td><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="exercicesHidden">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>' . $data['nom_exm'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $data['reps'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $data['poids'] . '</td>
                <td>Up!</td>
            </tr>
            ';

            //echo '<tr class="exercicesHidden"><td>Coucou je suis caché!</td></tr>';
        }

        echo '
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>'
```

I would like all the exercises are stored under one training, and when I click on it, it shows all the exercises from this training. 
I hope I gave you all the things to help me to correct this problem!

Comment: It will be much easier to send ajax request after click on "+" and return html with exercises as response

Comment: Very nice! I finally try to do it with ajax call, and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!